# ASP.Net MVC 2.0 Date validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to validate date value in dd/mm/yyyy format.I am getting error message even if I enter the date in correct format.

Here is my Code :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field.")]            
[RegularExpression(@"^((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|3[0-1])\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/[0-9]{4}$",ErrorMessage="Please enter in dd/mm/yyyy")]
[DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage="Please enter date.")]
public DateTime BeginningDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which one of the error messages is showing up?

Comment: And what date are you entering?

Comment: 'The value '28/12/2010' is not valid for BeginningDate'

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get comes from model binder, it has nothing in common with your attributes. I think, that if you want to check regular expression, you should use:

```
public string BeginningDate { get; set;}
```

and then convert it to `DateTime` by yourself, after model binding. You know that date has to be provided in specific format, but model binder is not that smart, uses web.config/server setting, and throws an error. Checking `DateTime` type by regular expression doesn't make sense, because it is already DateTime, not string. Model binding comes first and then validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateRegexAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
    public DateRegexAttribute(string pattern)
        : base(pattern)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        try
        {
            date = (DateTime) value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        var input = date.Date.ToShortDateString();

        Match match = Regex.Match(input, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return match.Success;
    }


    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(ErrorMessageString, Pattern);
        return new[] { rule };
    }
}
```